# Run Meteor from within a folder

Tags: javascript, apache, meteor

I've run `meteor build` to create my bundle, uploaded to the server, it runs fine, however the .css and .js paths are wrong, as it's using the root url. I need to run this from within a `/project` folder. Again it's running, but 404 on the files as they're not prefixed with `/project`.

---

eg. `http://domain.com/65d054cb90ff094804072528d222178ddbf625e22.js?meteor_js_resource=true 404 (Not Found)`

needs to be `http://domain.com/project/65d054cb90ff094804072528d222178ddbf625e22.js?meteor_js_resource=true`

---

I've tried using `ROOT_URL=http://domain.com/project node main.js`, that gives an `unknown path` error, i've also tried using `Meteor.absoluteUrl('project', {});` in conjuntion with rooturl but again, no avail.

Any of you fine people have any ideas? :) Thanks!

PS. It's running on an apache server with ProxyPass, if that's of relevance.

Answer (score 0):

You could instruct your apache to redirect those calls with a [ProxyPassMatch](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassmatch), such as:

```
<LocationMatch ^/(.*)meteor_js_resource=true$>
    ProxyPassMatch http://localhost/project/$1meteor_js_resource=true
</LocationMatch>
```